# Pandas dataframe or SQLite fuzzy search

Tags: python, sqlite, dataframe, fuzzy-search, fuzzywuzzy

I'm scraping multiple sports betting websites in order to compare the odds for each match across the websites.

My question is how to identify `match_id` from a match that already exists in the DB but has team names written in a different way.
Please feel free to add any approaches even if they don't use dataframes or SQLite.

The columns for `matches` table are:
match_id: int, sport: string, home_team: string, away_team: string, date: string (dd/mm/YYY)

So for each new match I want to verify if it already exists in the DB.
New match = (sport_to_check, home_team_to_check, away_team_to_check, date_to_check)
My pseudo-code is like:

```
    SELECT match_id FROM matches
    WHERE sport = (sport_to_check)
    AND date = (date_to_check)
    AND (fuzz(home_team, home_team_to_check) > 80 OR fuzz(away_team, away_team_to_check) > 80) //the fuzzy scores evaluation
```

If no match is found the new row would be inserted.

I believe there's no way to mix python with SQL like that so that's why I refer to it as "pseudo-code".
I can also pull the matches table into a Pandas dataframe and do the evaluation with it, if that works (how?...).
At any given time it isn't expected for matches table to have above a couple of thousand records.

Let me give you some examples of expected outputs. Where the solution is represented by "find(row)"
Having matches table in DB as:

```
    +----------+------------+-----------------------------+----------------------+------------+
    | match_id | sport      | home_team                   | visitor_team         | date       |
    +----------+------------+-----------------------------+----------------------+------------+
    | 84       | football   | confianca                   | cuiaba esporte clube | 24/11/2020 |
    | 209      | football   | cs alagoana                 | operario pr          | 24/11/2020 |
    | 184      | football   | grenoble foot 38            | as nancy lorraine    | 24/11/2020 |
    | 7        | football   | sv turkgucu-ataspor munchen | saarbrucken          | 24/11/2020 |
    | 414      | handball   | dinamo bucareste            | usam nimes           | 24/11/2020 |
    | 846      | handball   | benidorm                    | naturhouse la rioja  | 25/11/2020 |
    | 874      | handball   | cegledi                     | ferencvarosi tc      | 25/11/2020 |
    | 418      | handball   | lemvig-thyboron             | kif kolding          | 25/11/2020 |
    | 740      | ice hockey | tps                         | kookoo               | 25/11/2020 |
    | 385      | football   | stevenage                   | hull                 | 29/11/2020 |
    +----------+------------+-----------------------------+----------------------+------------+
```

And new matches to evaluate:

```
    +----------------+------------+---------------------+---------------------+------------+
    | row (for demo) | sport      | home_team           | visitor_team        | date       |
    +----------------+------------+---------------------+---------------------+------------+
    | A              | football   | confianca-se        | cuiaba mt           | 24/11/2020 |
    | B              | football   | csa                 | operario            | 24/11/2020 |
    | C              | football   | grenoble            | nancy               | 24/11/2020 |
    | D              | football   | sv turkgucu ataspor | 1 fc saarbrucken    | 24/11/2020 |
    | E              | handball   | dinamo bucuresti    | nimes               | 24/11/2020 |
    | F              | handball   | bm benidorm         | bm logrono la rioja | 25/11/2020 |
    | G              | handball   | cegledi kkse        | ftc budapest        | 25/11/2020 |
    | H              | handball   | lemvig              | kif kobenhavn       | 25/11/2020 |
    | I              | ice hockey | turku ps            | kookoo kouvola      | 25/11/2020 |
    | J              | football   | stevenage borough   | hull city           | 29/11/2020 |
    | K              | football   | west brom           | sheffield united    | 28/11/2020 |
    +----------------+------------+---------------------+---------------------+------------+
```

Outputs:

```
find(A) returns: 84  
find(B) returns: 209  
find(C) returns: 184  
find(D) returns: 7  
find(E) returns: 414  
find(F) returns: 846  
find(G) returns: 874  
find(H) returns: 418  
find(I) returns: 740  
find(J) returns: 385  
find(K) returns: (something like "not found" => I would then insert the new row)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically I filter down the original table by the given date and sport. then use fuzzywuzzy to find the best match between the home and visitors between the rows remaining:

**Setup:**

```
import pandas as pd

cols = ['match_id','sport','home_team','visitor_team','date']

df1 = pd.DataFrame([
['84','football','confianca','cuiaba esporte clube','24/11/2020'],
['209','football','cs alagoana','operario pr','24/11/2020'],
['184','football','grenoble foot 38','as nancy lorraine','24/11/2020'],
['7','football','sv turkgucu-ataspor munchen','saarbrucken','24/11/2020'],
['414','handball','dinamo bucareste','usam nimes','24/11/2020'],
['846','handball','benidorm','naturhouse la rioja','25/11/2020'],
['874','handball','cegledi','ferencvarosi tc','25/11/2020'],
['418','handball','lemvig-thyboron','kif kolding','25/11/2020'],
['740','ice hockey','tps','kookoo','25/11/2020'],
['385','football','stevenage','hull','29/11/2020']], columns=cols)


cols = ['row','sport','home_team','visitor_team','date']

df2 = pd.DataFrame([
['A','football','confianca-se','cuiaba mt','24/11/2020'],
['B','football','csa','operario','24/11/2020'],
['C','football','grenoble','nancy','24/11/2020'],
['D','football','sv turkgucu ataspor','1 fc saarbrucken','24/11/2020'],
['E','handball','dinamo bucuresti','nimes','24/11/2020'],
['F','handball','bm benidorm','bm logrono la rioja','25/11/2020'],
['G','handball','cegledi kkse','ftc budapest','25/11/2020'],
['H','handball','lemvig','kif kobenhavn','25/11/2020'],
['I','ice hockey','turku ps','kookoo kouvola','25/11/2020'],
['J','football','stevenage borough','hull city','29/11/2020'],
['K','football','west brom','sheffield united','28/11/2020']], columns=cols)
```

**Code:**

```
import pandas as pd
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
import string

def calculate_ratio(row):
    return fuzz.token_set_ratio(row['col1'],row['col2'] )

def find(df1, df2, row_search):
    alpha = df2.query('row == "{row_search}"'.format(row_search=row_search))
    sport = alpha.iloc[0]['sport']
    date = alpha.iloc[0]['date']
    home_team = alpha.iloc[0]['home_team']
    visitor_team = alpha.iloc[0]['visitor_team']
    
    beta = df1.query('sport == "{sport}" & date == "{date}"'.format(sport=sport,date=date))
    
    if len(beta) == 0:
        return 'Not found.'
    else:
        temp = pd.DataFrame({'match_id':list(beta['match_id']),'col1':list(beta['home_team'] + ' ' + beta['visitor_team']), 'col2':[home_team + ' ' + visitor_team]*len(beta)})
        temp['score'] = temp.apply(calculate_ratio, axis=1)
        temp = temp.sort_values('score', ascending=False)
        outcome = temp.head(1).iloc[0]['match_id']
        return outcome


for row_alpha in string.ascii_uppercase[0:11]:
    outcome = find(df1, df2, row_alpha)
    print ('{row_alpha} --> {outcome}'.format(row_alpha=row_alpha, outcome=outcome))
```

**Output:**

```
A --> 84
B --> 209
C --> 184
D --> 7
E --> 414
F --> 846
G --> 874
H --> 418
I --> 740
J --> 385
K --> Not found.
```